# Why does reading the CP15 c1 control register fail (ARMv7 inline asm)?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I want to disable the MMU, d-cache and i-cache on a ARMv7 chip (see below) to force reading and writing to memory in order to micro-benchmark memory power consumtion. The MWE:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("cp0\n");
#endif // DEBUG

        // disable MMU
        asm("mrc p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0"); // read
        asm("bic r1, r1, #0x1");          // MMU bit
        asm("mcr p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0"); // write

#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("cp1\n");
#endif // DEBUG

        // disable caches
        asm("mrc p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0");
        asm("bic r1, r1, #(0x1 << 12)");  // i-cache bit
        asm("bic r1, r1, #(0x1 << 2)");   // d-cache bit
        asm("mcr p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0");

#ifdef DEBUG
        printf("cp2\n");
#endif // DEBUG

        return 0;
}
```

However, executing the code above reveals:

```
$ gcc -O0 -o mem_test mem_test.c
$ sudo ./mem_test
cp0
```

So, the executable silently exits during the first block (*disable MMU*), more specifically the read instruction `mrc p15, 0, r1, c1, c0, 0`. What am I doing wrong?

The hardware I use is the [ODROID-XU3](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php?g_code=G140448267127), which has a Samsung Exynos 5422 processor with ARMv7 instruction set.

Comment: There is simply **no way** a multiuser/multitasking operating system with a meaningful protection model is going to let you disable the MMU **from userspace**.  Likely you can't even do that in kernel mode (and continue running), unless you are very careful about where the code doing it is positioned in physical memory.  Disabling the caches might be more realistic, but even then is probably going to have to be done in the kernel.

Comment: If you are serious about benchmarking the hardware in the abstract like this, you probably want a small bare-metal program (derived from a bootloader?) or else a bit of code into which the kernel will call that will suspend everything else and run this test, then either output the result somehow before crashing completely, or manage to somehow return to normal operation.

Comment: Makes sense that this is not possible from user space. I was not thinking much as the documentation doesn't mention any issues. How would you suggest to maximize memory load without disabling the MMU and/or d-cache, i.e. avoiding cache hits?

Comment: Disabling the dcache, given cooperation from the kernel, does seem reasonable.  Why do you want to disable the MMU?  In terms of benchmarking, what you'd really want to do is minimize context switching to other tasks.  Often that is done by just running a lot of what you want to benchmark, for a while, in order to minimize the impact of background stuff.  Of course you'll get the cleanest result for the hardware itself if what you want to test can be representatively done as a compact bit of kernel or bare metal code run with interrupts disabled.

Comment: Sounds reasonable -- thanks! I'll try to disabled the d-cache from a kernel module and benchmark from there. Would you mind converting the essence of your comments to an answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: Even disabling the entire cache seems a bit silly - why not just allocate some memory, set up a non-cacheable mapping for it, and go wild?